# Can using multiple triggers cause performance issues?

Tags: performance, triggers, google-apps-script

Using FormRanger with a form/google spreadsheet, we have 3 triggers: on every form submit; on every spreadsheet edit; and every five minutes. Will using all 3 cause conflicts and/or slowness of the google form/spreadsheet (form responses)?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

No, the parallel triggers will not cause any performance issues. Each invocation will run in it's own copy of the spreadsheet, and there is no direct interaction between them.

All scripts will contribute towards your daily service limits.